# Spring Security custom authentication and remember me

Tags: spring, spring-security, remember-me

I used [this](http://krams915.blogspot.de/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration-using_26.html) tutorial to implement a custom authentication manager. Login and logout works fine.

Now I want to use spring security remember-me authentication. As far as I know, remember-me requires a userDetailService. So I implemented a custom `userDetailService`.

On the login page I added a checkbox with name `_spring_security_remember_me`. But, remember-me doesn't work. The remember-me cookie is not set after succesful login. I think this is a configuration problem or do I need to implement a custom remember me to work with custom authentication ?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="_spring_security_remember_me">stay signed in
```

My Spring-Security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/login?error=true"
            entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" >

        <!-- Zugriff auf /login für alle erlauben -->   
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
        <!-- resources -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <!--<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"/> -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <!-- Zugriff auf /admin/** einschränken -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>


        <security:logout 
                invalidate-session="true" 
                logout-success-url="/login?logout=true" 
                logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"/>

        <security:custom-filter ref="blacklistFilter" before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR"/>
        <security:custom-filter ref="authenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>

        <!-- Session Timeout Seite setzen und
            Session Fixation Attack Protection einschalten --> 
        <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/login?timeout=true"
            session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">

             <!-- Maxmale Anzahl von Session per User (Doppelanmeldung) --> 
             <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="3"
                error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
        </security:session-management> 
        <security:remember-me key="myAppKey" token-validity-seconds="864000" user-service-ref="customUserDetailService"/>
    </security:http>

    <!-- custom user service -->
    <bean id="customUserDetailService" class="com.stefan.app.security.CustomUserDetailsService">
        <property name="userBean" ref="userBean" />
    </bean>

    <!--  Custom filter to deny unwanted users even though registered -->
    <bean id="blacklistFilter" class="com.stefan.app.security.filter.BlacklistFilter" />

    <!-- Custom filter for username and password. The real customization is done in the customAthenticationManager -->
    <bean id="authenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
        p:authenticationManager-ref="customAuthenticationManager"
        p:authenticationFailureHandler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        p:authenticationSuccessHandler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

    <!-- Custom authentication manager. In order to authenticate, username and password must not be the same -->
    <bean id="customAuthenticationManager" class="com.stefan.app.security.CustomAuthenticationManager">
        <property name="userBean" ref="userBean" />
    </bean>

    <jee:local-slsb id="userBean" jndi-name="java:global/com.stefan.auctionnsiper-ear/app.ejb/UserBean!com.stefan.app.user.UserBeanLocal"
                business-interface="com.stefan.app.user.UserBeanLocal"/>

    <!-- We just actually need to set the default failure url here -->
    <bean id="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"
        p:defaultFailureUrl="/login?error=true" />

     <!-- We just actually need to set the default target url here -->
    <bean id="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
        p:defaultTargetUrl="/products" />

    <!-- The AuthenticationEntryPoint is responsible for redirecting the user to a particular page, like a login page,
            whenever the server sends back a response requiring authentication -->
    <!-- See Spring-Security Reference 5.4.1 for more info -->
    <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        p:loginFormUrl="/login"/>

    <!-- The tag below has no use but Spring Security needs it to autowire the parent property of 
            org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager. Otherwise we get an error 
            A probable bug. This is still under investigation-->
    <security:authentication-manager/>
</beans>
```

Comment: hello @Stefan, i am also facing same problem. how you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Check:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815277/spring-security-tokenbasedremembermeservices-cookiename-ignored
- http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?130600-Spring-security-remember-me-cookie-configuration-example

---

Try this:

```
<security:http>
   ...
   <security:remember-me services-ref="rememberMeServices" />
</security:http>

<bean id="rememberMeServices" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="customUserDetailService"/>
    <property name="tokenValiditySeconds" value="864000"/>
    <property name="cookieName" value="SPRING_RM"/>
    <property name="key" value="myAppKey"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: thanks JoGo. I have tried your suggestion but without success. the remember cookie is not set. I check the links and change authenticationFilter: <bean id="authenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
  <property name="authenticationManager" ref="customAuthenticationManager" />
  <property name="rememberMeServices" ref="rememberMeServices" />
 </bean> Now the Cookie is set aber remember me doens't work. any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Besides what JoGo said, don't forget to set the "rememberMeServices" property on your "authenticationFilter", that is:

```
<bean id="authenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter"
    p:authenticationManager-ref="customAuthenticationManager"
    p:authenticationFailureHandler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler"
    p:authenticationSuccessHandler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler"
    p:rememberMeServices-ref="rememberMeServices" />
```

Additionally you'll probably need to remove the remember me cookie when the user logs out, so he's not automatically logged in:

```
<security:logout 
    invalidate-session="true" 
    logout-success-url="/login?logout=true" 
    logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
    delete-cookies="SPRING_RM"      
    />
```

I hope this helps.