# Spring security Remember me and Custom Authentication provider

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

issue with spring remember me

in my spring security application i have custom authentication provider that authenticate and return custom authentication object and authentication works perfectly but i have issue with spring Remember me service it's not working correctly

but when i authenticate through normal spring security, by using UserDetailService then Remember me works perfectly my code for both is as below

```
package com.websopti.wotms.auth;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.websopti.wotms.entity.User;
import com.websopti.wotms.enums.ErrorKey;
import com.websopti.wotms.service.UserService;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    public UserService userService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        String email = authentication.getPrincipal().toString();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        String username = null;

        try {
            username = userService.authenticate(email, password);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(username != null && !username.equals("0")){

            User user = userService.findByEmail(email);

            if (user != null) {

                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().name()));
                return (new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, authorities));

            } else {

                User newUser = new User();
                newUser.setName(username);
                newUser.setEmail(email);
                newUser.setPassword(password);

                userService.register(newUser);

                newUser = userService.findById(newUser.getId());                
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(newUser.getRole().name()));

                return (new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(newUser, null, authorities));
            }

        } else {

            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(ErrorKey.USER_NOT_FOUND.name());

        }


    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {

        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

if i use following code for authenticate then it works okay

```
package com.websopti.wotms.auth;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.websopti.wotms.entity.User;
import com.websopti.wotms.enums.ErrorKey;
import com.websopti.wotms.service.UserService;

@Service
public class AuthenticationService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    public UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userService.findByEmail(email);

        if(user != null)
            return user;
        else
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(ErrorKey.USER_NOT_FOUND.name());
    }

}
```

can some one guide me what is the issue here in my code?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html#remember-me-persistent-token)

> Note that both implemementations require a UserDetailsService. If you
>   are using an authentication provider which doesn't use a
>   UserDetailsService (for example, the LDAP provider) then it won't work
>   unless you also have a UserDetailsService bean in your application
>   context.

Example default remember-me uses [TokenBasedRememberMeServices](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/TokenBasedRememberMeServices.java) processAutoLoginCookie() method retrieves the userDetails from the cookie to validate the user/password details. So you need a custom userDetailsService check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25403255/spring-remember-me-with-custom-authentication-provider?lq=1) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868419/spring-security-custom-authentication-and-remember-me)

UPDATE:

Basically remember me functionality does 2 things

1. After successful login, it creates a "rememeber-me" browser cookie with a  token based on username,password ( token can be computed and persisted in db if needed or it can be on the fly computed hash of user,password).
2. When the user tries to access the secured page without any session (session is expired because of timeout), then RememberMe service will try to autoLogin the user by retrieving the user details from the cookie and can verify user details if needed.

If you don't have a UserDetailsService which returns the UserDetails info, then you need to implement RememberMeServices like TokenBasedRememberMeServices and adapt the code.

Comment: here in my application i'm authenticate user through WebService so i need username and password entered by user by getting that credential i'm authenticating so there is no use of UserDetailService because i'm returning Authentication object from CustomeAuthenticationProvider.
i have checked links but i'm using springboot not getting much idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem ,and add`auth.userDetailsService(userService);` fix it

```java
  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationService userDetailsService;
  @Autowired
  private CustomAuthenticationProvider provider;
  @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        //将验证过程交给自定义验证工具
        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Spring custom authentication provider you need to make your own remember me service and configure it in to spring security config file.

Below is the link for reference:
https://samerabdelkafi.wordpress.com/2016/01/25/secure-angularjs-application-with-spring-security/

problem with remember me and custom Authentication provider is :

1. You already authenticated in custom authentication provider.
2. After that remember me filter in spring security chain again going to call userdetails service. At that time userdetail service take authentication principal as a input parameter and you cant get any user detail from dbo and it will not execute this filter.

> public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String mobile) throws
>   UsernameNotFoundException { 
>   System.out.println(mobile); //here you can
>   get the authenticated principal user object if you already authenticated and you
>   will not get any user deatils. }

I am not sure below solution is right or not but it works fine for me.

> ```
> public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
>
>     Customer user = null;
>
>     user = customerDataManager.findCustomerByMobile(auth.getName());
>     if ((user == null)) {
>         throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username or password");
>     }
>     final Authentication result = super.authenticate(auth);
>
>     return result;
> }
> ```

instead of returning UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken object return authentication object.